# Disable Undefined Property error in PHP Devsense extension on VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I just added the PHP extension by Devsense to my VSCode and now it's lighting up like a Christmas tree. I want to disable the Intellisense option for unknown/undefined properties.

Here is the [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GD6w.png)
and the error message
`Undefined property: MY_Model::$load PHP(PHP0416)`
And a [link](https://www.devsense.com/en/updates/vs/v1-67#unknown-property-diagnostic-and-code-fix-php0416) to the post where they talk about adding it

I saw some options for Intelliphense where you could set `"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties": false`
in the vscode settings.json, but I couldn't find anything that would work for this extension.

The fix described [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=86059&pid=405043#pid405043) in the 3rd post to add the property in a comment does work, but is not feasible in the codebases I am working in. I need something more like the second post, where I can just disable the check altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. Leaving it here because It took me way too long.

You just have to [exclude the error code](https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/problems#phpproblemsexclude), in this case error code 0416

Answer (score 2):

1 - Open Settings.json :  ctrl + shift + P  and type 'settings.json'
2 - Select 'Open User Settings (JSON)
3 - At the end of file, add this code:

```json
"php.problems.exclude" : {
  "/" : [416],
  "vendor/" : true,
}
```